# QGIS 3.16.4: Graphical modeler not running

Tags: qgis-modeler

Does anyone know the error that a graphical model can not be run at all?

Following procedure:

1. Go to "Browser" in QGIS.
2. Execute *.model3.
3. Do the necessary stuff like input file and output file.
4. Click on "Run".

There is no error, nothing in "Log" and no output file.
An input file from the local hard disk did not change anything.
It affects not only one model, but several. A colleague also tested it, there all models worked.

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure the model actually works? What should the model do? What input data do you have?

Comment: Thank you, I added some information.

Comment: Have you tried building a simple model and running it? E.g. one for reprojecting a shape file.

Comment: Yes, I tried a simple model (just with a buffer) and found out the following: 
- Case 1: Right click at the model via QGIS browser: "edit model"; then no editing, but "start" the model (green arrow) -> result: model was executed
- Case 2: Right click at the model via QGIS browser: "run model"; then "start" the model -> result: nothing happens
Looks like a bug to me, doesn't it?

Comment: I think I now know, what you're talking about: Models simply do not run, when you drag&drop them into QGIS - they only run when started from the QGIS modeller. Did you observe this behaviour? So yes, this most likely is a bug.

Comment: No, I didn't drag&drop it into QGIS. I navigated to the model via browser (in the german QGIS the widget is called "browser"). In the content menu of the model are the both options "edit model" and "run model".

Comment: Yeah, but I think drag&drop and running from the browser work similarly. I'll open a bug report/check whether one exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and bug reporting! Then my suggestion would be to remove the option "run model" from the content menu of the browser as long as the bug exists.

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44824  - bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems to be a bug: Nothing happens, when right clicking at the model via QGIS browser: "run model" and then start the model. It is probably related to the bug, that models simply do not run, when you drag&drop them into QGIS.
Workaround: Right click at the model via QGIS browser: "edit model"; then no editing, but "start" the model with the green arrow.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in QGIS which was resolved with https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/43716.

It should now work with the latest QGIS LR / LTR releases (curently 3.20.2 / 3.16.10).